# Meteor - on button click retrieve single document from database and display

Tags: node.js, mongodb, templates, meteor

I'm trying to retrieve a single random document from the database on a button click. When the page loads, it does get a single document and displays on the webpage; but when I try to click the button to retrieve another random document and display on the webpage it does not work.

The issue is passing the object to the html file. Yes, I am new to Meteor/ template system.

main.html

```
<body>
<ul>
   {{#each resolutions}}
    {{> resolution}}
   {{/each}}
</ul>
</body>

<template name="resolution">
<li>
<span class="text">{{question}}</span><br>
<button type="button" name="button" class="change-question">Change Question</button>
<br>
</li>
</template>
```

main.js

```
  Template.resolution.events({
'click .change-question': function(event, instance){

  var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
  var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
  // choose a random item by skipping N items
  var item = Resolutions.findOne({},{
    skip: random
  });
  var objArray = $.makeArray(item);

  instance.question.set(objArray);
// window.alert("sometext" + objArray);
}
});

  Template.body.helpers({
  resolutions: function() {
    var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
    var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
    // choose a random item by skipping N items
    var item = Resolutions.findOne({},{
      skip: random
    });
    var objArray = $.makeArray(item);
    return objArray;
  }
  });
```

The ERROR message says 'cannot read property set of undefined'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Reactive Variable like this:
main.html

```
<body>
<ul>
   {{#each resolutions}}
    {{> resolution}}
   {{/each}}
</ul>
</body>

<template name="resolution">
   <li>
      <span class="text">{{questionData}}</span><br>
      <button type="button" name="button" class="change-question">Change  Question</button>
     <br>
   </li>
</template>
```

main.js

```
var questionData = new ReactiveVar(null);
Template.resolution.rendered = function () {
    questionData.set(this.data);
}
Template.resolution.events({
    'click .change-question': function (event, instance) {

        var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
        var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
        // choose a random item by skipping N items
        var item = Resolutions.findOne({}, {
            skip: random
        });
        var objArray = $.makeArray(item);

        questionData.set(objArray);
        // window.alert("sometext" + objArray);
    }
});
Template.resolution.events({
    questionData: function () {
        if(questionData.get()) {
           return questionData.get().question;
        }
    }
})
Template.body.helpers({
    resolutions: function () {
        var collection_size = Resolutions.find().count();
        var random = Math.floor(Random.fraction() * collection_size);
        // choose a random item by skipping N items
        var item = Resolutions.findOne({}, {
            skip: random
        });
        var objArray = $.makeArray(item);
        return objArray;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Sapna. I tried that and it gave me a different error message 'instance.data.question.set' is not a function.

Comment: Have you tried "instance.data.question = objArray" ?

Comment: You can also go for reactive variable. If you want I can show you it's usage in terms of your example?

Comment: Hi Sapna. If you could give me an example with Reactive would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Silvio, I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know.